# I'm trying to create UIStoryboard but on error occurs in my code

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vc1")as? DetailViewController
    //vc?.image = img[indexPath.row]!
    //vc?.name = imageArray[indexPath.row] storyboard
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
}
```

Error is:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'storyboard'

Comment: Where is defined `storyboard`? Did you meant `let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "someName", bundle: nil)`?

Comment: What class is this function in?

Comment: I am using UICollectinView inside UITableView so I'm facing  this error please help me....

Answer (score 0):

Look into this:

```
    // Case: When the next ViewController is existed in the same Storyboard.
    let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ControllerIdentifier") as! YourViewController
    // pass data here to the next controller.
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)


    // Case: When the next ViewController is exists in other Storyboard.
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryboardName", bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ControllerIdentifier") as! YourViewController
    // pass data here to the next controller.
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

Note: As you are using this line 'withIdentifier: "vc1"', I would like to suggest you that always assign the Storyboard ID for a ViewController same as ViewController's class name. Make it as a habit, it will be helpful because you don't need to remember the Storyboard Id what you set. So keep the thing simple.

Answer (score -1):

Check in the properties of `DetailViewController` in `Main.storyboard` and see if the storyboard id is set properly. According to your code it should be `vc1`

[image]